# How can i link GLFW and Dear ImGUI in CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw, imgui

the last few days i was messing with CMake, and everything worked fine, except that i can't find a way to link ImGUI with GLFW

Everything is build from source

Here is the error :

```
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target glad
[  2%] Built target glad
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target stb
[  5%] Built target stb
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target glfw
[ 29%] Built target glfw
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target imgui
[ 30%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/lib/imgui/imgui.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/lib/imgui/imgui_demo.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/lib/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp.o
[ 34%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/lib/imgui/imgui_tables.cpp.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/lib/imgui/imgui_widgets.cpp.o
[ 37%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/lib/imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp.o
/home/erik/Workspace/LearnOpenGL/lib/imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp:45:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
   45 | #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/build.make:146: CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/lib/imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:228: CMakeFiles/imgui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:156: all] Error 2
```

And here is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(LearnOpenGL)


set(SRC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source")
set(LIB_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib")

set(SOURCES "${SRC_DIR}/Main.cpp"
    )


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${SRC_DIR}")

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)


# GLFW

set(GLFW_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/glfw")

set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Build the GLFW example programs")
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Build the GLFW test programs")
set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Build the GLFW documentation")
set(GLFW_INSTALL OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Generate installation target")

add_subdirectory("${GLFW_DIR}")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "glfw" "${GLFW_LIBRARIES}")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${GLFW_DIR}/include")
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE")


# Glad

set(GLAD_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/glad")

add_library("glad" "${GLAD_DIR}/src/glad.c")

target_include_directories("glad" PRIVATE "${GLAD_DIR}/include")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${GLAD_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "glad" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")


# GLM 

set(GLM_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/glm")

add_subdirectory(${GLM_DIR})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "glm")


# STB

set(STB_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/stb")

add_library("stb" "${STB_DIR}/src/stb_image.cpp")

target_include_directories("stb" PRIVATE "${STB_DIR}/include")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${STB_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "stb" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")


# Freetype

set(FREETYPE_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/freetype")

add_subdirectory("${FREETYPE_DIR}")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "${FREETYPE_LIBRARIES}")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${FREETYPE_DIR}/include")


# ImGUI

set(IMGUI_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/imgui")

add_library("imgui" "${IMGUI_DIR}/imgui.cpp"
                  "${IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_demo.cpp"
                  "${IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_draw.cpp"
                  "${IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_tables.cpp"
                  "${IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_widgets.cpp"
                  
                  "${IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp"
                  "${IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp")

target_include_directories("imgui" PRIVATE "${IMGUI_DIR}")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${IMGUI_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} "imgui" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")
```

And here is my folder construction

```
 1. build
 2. lib
    -  freetype
    -  glad
    -  glfw
    -  glm
    -  imgui
    -  stb
 3. source
    -  Main.cpp
 4. CMakeLists.txt
```

Here is my question : How i can tell imgui that glfw is already here and he can use it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a GitHub repo with your code in it? This build is just _so_ far afield from anything you should reasonably do in CMake that I'm tempted to help you just re-write it, but I can't do that without being able to play with it myself. If you don't want to share your code with me, I _urge_ you to use [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/) and `find_package` to manage dependencies in CMake.

Comment: For example, calling `add_subdirectory` will not set `FREETYPE_LIBRARIES`. I think you've confused this with `find_package`. It looks like you're writing your own mini build systems for STB, Glad, and ImGUI. Maybe don't do that?

Comment: i'll create a github so u can see

Comment: https://github.com/real2k/LearnOpenGL here it is

Comment: hello @ErikTellier is it possible to share the structure of your project via github link. I am stuck too .

Comment: hi, the project is long gone, but i suggest you to try VCPKG it's fairly good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your build should consist of nothing but the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(LearnOpenGL)

## Find dependencies
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
find_package(glad REQUIRED)
find_package(glm REQUIRED)
find_package(freetype REQUIRED)
find_package(imgui REQUIRED)

# stb does not have a CMake build, but is header-only
find_path(STB_INCLUDE_DIRS "stb.h") 

## Create main executable
add_executable(main source/Main.cpp)
target_include_directories(main 
  PRIVATE 
    ${STB_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/source"
)
target_link_libraries(
  main
  PRIVATE
    freetype
    glfw
    glad::glad
    glm::glm
    imgui::imgui
)
```

If you aren't using CMake 3.20, (a) you *should be*, but (b) you can try with an earlier version. But *never* put a version below the one you test with. CMake is only backwards compatible, not forwards compatible.

If you only need freetype as a dependency of imgui, then you can remove the references to it in the CMakeLists.txt.

To build this, you'll *want* to use vcpkg. To that end, create a file called `vcpkg.json` next to your CMakeLists.txt with the following contents:

```
{
  "name": "learn-opengl",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": [
    "glfw3",
    "glad",
    "glm",
    "freetype",
    "stb",
    {
      "name": "imgui",
      "features": ["freetype", "glfw-binding", "opengl3-glad-binding"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is just telling `vcpkg` which dependencies you want, and that you want `imgui` built with `freetype` support and the `glfw` bindings.

Then you just need to run three commands.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg.git
$ cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$PWD/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
$ cmake --build build
```

The only thing here that might be unexpected is setting `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`, this is just telling CMake to use vcpkg. The first time this runs, vcpkg will download your dependencies, build them, cache them in `~/.cache/vcpkg` and install them into your build folder. Subsequent runs will build *just* your code.

This sequence successfully built your code for me on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS machine.

---

To make this easier, consider creating a `CMakePresets.json` file, also in your root directory, with the following contents:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 20,
    "patch": 0
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "displayName": "Default Config",
      "description": "Default build using Make and vcpkg",
      "generator": "Unix Makefiles",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release",
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "${sourceDir}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "default-msvc",
      "displayName": "Default MSVC",
      "description": "Default build using Visual Studio and vcpkg",
      "generator": "Visual Studio 16 2019",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "${sourceDir}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can just run `cmake --preset=default` instead of the longer command above.

Comment: i do like your answer but at the same time not, when i created my project the first things i wanted to do is building everything from source, to avoid installing libs and libs. 
And Glad & ImGUI don't have a cmake implementation. Thanks anyway

Comment: vcpkg does compile from source. The way you're trying to compile from source will not work because that's just architecturally not how CMake operates.

Comment: i'll try then and comeback to u when i manage to make it work

Comment: Look, CMake is turing complete, so there's probably some way to make it work. It isn't worth your (or anyone's) time to do so. Insisting on the _worst possible process_ will not get you very far. If you don't want to use vcpkg you can do what it does: download each dependency and install them all to a common prefix, then call with build (the exact same CMakeLists as above) with `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` set.

Comment: i followed your answer but i got an error saying : 

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findglfw3.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "glfw3" with any of
  the following names:

    glfw3Config.cmake
    glfw3-config.cmake

Comment: Add the installation prefix of "glfw3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "glfw3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "glfw3"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

Comment: It sounds like you either didn't create the `vcpkg.json` or you didn't set the toolchain file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233876/discussion-between-erik-tellier-and-alex-reinking).

Comment: How can i properly adapt that configuration to windows10 without visual studio?
And getting both preset for my project so i can easily work on both os?

Comment: It should be as easy as creating a `windows` preset with the `Visual Studio 16 2019` generator. I can try it myself later. Vcpkg works on major platforms.

Comment: if u can explain to me how to do it when u got time I would be grateful.

Comment: @ErikTellier - I updated my answer to work on Windows with your latest code.

Comment: Hey if you still read the comment here, mister.
Do you have an answer for that question using vcpkg and mingw

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68144821/vcpkg-isnt-working-on-windows-with-mingw

Comment: @ErikTellier @AlexReinking any chance one of you would be able to please help me out? At the moment I am following the process suggested by Alex above and running into the same error that Erik ran into where find_package is unable to find glfw3. I was able to successfully run the commands and I have tried deleting my build directory and re-running the commands which worked for Erik to solve that issue. Still running into the same problem after doing this. I've pushed my code to this branch `https://github.com/Blargian/min_span_tree_visualizer/tree/EM-44-Integrate-SFML-and-a-graphing-library `

Comment: @Blargian - please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)